# Firefox plugin or way to monitor ALL request data, including headers and content downloaded to browser

Tags: http, firefox, firebug, header

I am having problems getting ALL of the information that is downloaded to a browser.  For example, I want a plugin, ideally a firefox plugin to download the HTML content and monitor when I get a 302 redirect, and all header information.

So far,  use Live HTTP Headers and Firebug.  Both are fine.

With Live HTTP headers, I can't monitor the data that is downloaded (e.g. the html data)
Firebug is worse, because I can't monitor the headers and I can't monitor the full requests.  For example, Firebug won't show you all of the content that is downloaded, just the last set of requests.  E.g. redirects will clear the Firebug net monitoring.

I am on win32

Comment: Related, you can block new Firefox tabs to be able to view all requests in the built-in network monitor: https://superuser.com/questions/1411992/how-to-view-log-of-network-requests-across-tabs-in-firefox/1465774#1465774

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try ***[Tamper data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966)*** firefox add-on, an extension to *track and modify http/https requests*.

You can find a [nice tutorial here](http://jimbojw.com/wiki/index.php?title=Tamper_Data).

**Firebug + Tamper Data is the best couple of firefox tools I cannot live without**.

Comment: Perfect solution.  Thanks a lot.

It does have a bug though.  It doesn't download the content for javascript client side redirects.

E.g. I get a -1 error for body onload=document.location=http://url.com

It won't download that content.  But that is OK.

Comment: say, not available

Answer (score 11):

I could find all requests with all info and redirects without installing anything. Check **Web Console** in **Tools -> Web Developer**.

Comment: Be sure that `Log` and `XHR` are checked on the `Net` dropdown to get this functionality.

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at [Fiddler](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&ved=0CAsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fiddlertool.com%2F&ei=jB3rSuf7EoqllAf0-KX_BA&usg=AFQjCNENlmLsxhXXbm04SsymdSwZIL9URg)?

Answer (score 1):

While not a firefox plugin, [Ethereal](http://www.ethereal.com/) is great.  Start it up and do your browsing as usual.

Comment: Ethereal is now called Wireshark and you will need to use the SSLKEYLOGFILE environment variable to decrypt HTTPS: https://ask.wireshark.org/question/1088/step-by-step-ssl-decrypt-with-wireshark/

Answer (score 0):

Ethereal (wireshark) is nice, but also complicated.  Last I used it with HTTP, it didn't support decoding of HTTPS (secure) packets, though that may have changed.  There are actually ton's out there now, but I personally like / use HTTPFox [https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6647/].

Comment: It's never going to support decoding of HTTPS doing what it does, which is capture packets on the wire between your browser and the server. HTTPS content is encrypted specifically to avoid such capturing and decoding.

Comment: @interfect it is possible to decrypt HTTPS with Wireshark if you configure it correctly and have control over Firefox: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651113/firefox-plugin-or-way-to-monitor-all-request-data-including-headers-and-content#comment108635210_1651126
And HTTPFox Firefox addon can see HTTPS traffic by default but it is not compatible with the latest Firefox version.

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP monitor and analyzer addon for Firefox

[HttpFox Firefox Plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/httpfox/)

Answer (score 0):

Outdated accepted answer,

use firebug then select Net > All >  POST > you'll be able to see the parameters there.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use a tool like `mitmproxy` to view and edit HTTP / HTTPS requests and responses, as well as WebSocket messages: https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy

You can also export a request as a cURL command to edit and replay it without mitmproxy.

The software is open source and written in Python. It provides an API if you want to automate modifications. If you don't want to use the command line, there is also a web version `mitmweb`. The command `mitmdump` can be used to view traffic in a non-interactive mode.